# akka immutable message with final reference to a list

Tags: java, message, immutability, akka

In the akka docs they specify that a message must be immutable an reference an example message that contains a final reference to a list. If java lists are mutable how is this OK?

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/java/untyped-actors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the code and you will see that they make sure that the list is immutable:

```
public class ImmutableMessage {
private final int sequenceNumber;
private final List<String> values;

public ImmutableMessage(int sequenceNumber, List<String> values) {
    this.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;
    // HERE -- NEXT LINE MAKE SURE THAT THE LIST IS NOT MUTABLE:
    this.values = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(values));
}

public int getSequenceNumber() {
    return sequenceNumber;
}

public List<String> getValues() {
    return values;
}
}
```

Comment: Is it actually really necessary to use Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(values)) instead of Collections.unmodifiableList(values)?

Comment: @Bouncer yes if you want to keep the values stored in the array `values` at the time the constructor is invoked. Otherwise, if someone else modifies the original array, `this.values` will be modified as well.